# Pass a file path to a Javascript function from C# code behind

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, code-behind

I have this javascript function in a .aspx file.

```
<script>
function somefun(value) 
{
       document.getElementById("myFlash").SetVariable("player:jsUrl", value);
       document.getElementById("myFlash").SetVariable("player:jsPlay", "");

}
</script>
```

I'm calling and passing a value to that function inside a **onclick event** in the **code-behind** class.

```
protected void DownloadFile(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string filePath1 = "Audio/songname.mp3";

        ScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptBlock(this, typeof(string), "Registering", String.Format("somefun('{0}');", filePath1), true);


    }
```

But when I click the button, I'm getting this error.
**'Unable to get property 'SetVariable' of undefined or null reference'**

The javascript function is correct and I checked it. I think something is wrong with the way I passing the parameter.

Answer (score 0):

> The javascript function is correct and I checked it.

I don't think so. The error message suggests that `document.getElementById("myFlash")` return `null`, therefore you got an exception when trying to call `SetVariable()` on a null reference. This has nothing to do with the function parameter, at least not yet.

Comment: When I call the javascript function in the aspx page, it works perfect. I called it like this, inside the body tag.    <button onclick="somefun('Audio/Audio/songname.mp3')">English</button>. That's why I said, checked and correct.